# DOMContentLoaded does not fire on IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

First of all: I'm new to coding in generel. i just started 3 months ago.

I'm setting up a website for a friend. The navbar of it should responsevely change it's html content what works fine on every device i tested. but when i try to set the innerHtml of my nav-ul with DOMContentLoaded, something goes wrong but only on the IOS Safari.
unfortunately i can't use any browser developer tools on my ios safari.

Here is my app.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const rect = document.querySelector(".main-container");
  const screenWidth = rect.getBoundingClientRect().width;

  if (screenWidth <= 800) {
    document.getElementById("navbar-list").innerHTML = 
     `<li>
        <a href="tel:xxxxx">
          <img src="./vector/phone1.png" alt="" class="icon">
          <p id="number">
            Anrufen
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hallo! ich bin ein text der in einem whatsapp button programmiert ist auf peters website!&phone=xxxxx">
          <img src="./vector/icons8-whatsapp.svg" alt="" class="icon">
          <p>
            WhatsApp
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>`
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar-list").innerHTML = 
     `<li>
        <a href="#home">
          Home
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#faecher">
          Fächer
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#konzept">
          Konzept
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#reviews">
          Ergebnisse
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contact">
          Kontakt
        </a>
      </li>`
   }
});
```

Do i miss some await-stuff because i have to mention some async stuff?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use [Safari Web Inspector](https://appletoolbox.com/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/) to view and debug iOS Safari page. You will need an iOS device and a desktop/laptop Mac.

Comment: @terrymorse 
yes i know, but unfortunately i have no matching cable to connect my iOS device with my macbook. But thank you for the hint! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you log `document.readyState` inside of that callback? If it's not `loading` that means the event fired before the event listener was registered.

More here:https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651215

Comment: Thank you! with the workaround on the link you'v posted, it works fine!